# How to map lambda expressions in Java

Tags: java, python, lambda

I'm coming from Python, and trying to understand how lambda expressions work differently in Java. In Python, you can do stuff like:

```
opdict = { "+":lambda a,b: a+b, "-": lambda a,b: a-b, 
           "*": lambda a,b: a*b, "/": lambda a,b: a/b }
sum = opdict["+"](5,4)
```

How can I accomplish something similar in Java? I have read a bit on Java lambda expressions, and it seems I have to declare an interface first, and I'm unclear about how and why you need to do this.

Edit:  I attempted to do this myself with a custom interface.  Here's the code I have tried:

```
Map<String, MathOperation> opMap = new HashMap<String, MathOperation>(){
        { put("+",(a,b)->b+a);
          put("-",(a,b)->b-a);
          put("*",(a,b)->b*a);
          put("/",(a,b)->b/a); }
};
...
...

interface MathOperation {
   double operation(double a, double b);
}
```

However, this gives an error:

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface.

Where exactly do I declare the interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy enough to do with a [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) in Java 8:

```
final Map<String, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>> opdict = new HashMap<>();
opdict.put("+", (x, y) -> x + y);
opdict.put("-", (x, y) -> x - y);
opdict.put("*", (x, y) -> x * y);
opdict.put("/", (x, y) -> x / y);

int sum = opdict.get("+").apply(5, 4);
System.out.println(sum);
```

The syntax is a bit more verbose than Python to be sure, and using `getOrDefault` on `opdict` would probably be preferable as to avoid a scenario in which you use an operator that doesn't exist, but this should get the ball rolling at least.

If you're exclusively working with `int`s, using `IntBinaryOperator` would be preferable, as this would take care of any generic typing that you'd have to do.

```
final Map<String, IntBinaryOperator> opdict = new HashMap<>();
opdict.put("+", (x, y) -> x + y);
opdict.put("-", (x, y) -> x - y);
opdict.put("*", (x, y) -> x * y);
opdict.put("/", (x, y) -> x / y);

int sum = opdict.get("+").applyAsInt(5, 4);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: `IntBinaryOperator` might be slightly better.

Comment: @PaulBoddington:  Yes, you're definitely right, but then we run into an awkward scenario:  what if we want to be able to add things that aren't just ints together?  I'll include what you've shown me though, thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah those kinds of scenarios can be annoying, When we eventually get `Map.of("+", (x, y) -> x + y, "-", ...` this will be almost as short as the python version.

Comment: Great answer, just one followup question; How would I do this if I wanted to implement my own interface? It is my understanding that when you instantiate the interface using a lambda expression, you are basically implementing the abstract method of the interface. Please see the edit I've made to the post

Comment: @SimonZhu:  I don't notice any compilation failures when I use your custom interface.  I'm running the latest (I think) Java in 1.8.60; be sure you're up to date as well.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use an enum:

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS((x, y) -> x + y),
    MINUS((x, y) -> x - y),
    TIMES((x, y) -> x * y),
    DIVIDE((x, y) -> x / y);

    private final IntBinaryOperator op;

    Operation(IntBinaryOperator op) { this.op = op; }

    public int apply(int x, int y) { return op.applyAsInt(x, y); }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int sum = Operation.PLUS.apply(5, 4);
```

This is not as succinct as other solutions, but using an enum rather than a `String` means that when you type `Operation.` into an IDE, you will be presented with the list of all possible operations.